# Recommendation for easily breakable bike lock

Tags: lock

I want to purchase a bike lock which I can break easily if it gets jammed, preferably without any tool(or a very small/light tool which I can carry in my bag-pack).
I have tried two locks and both of them jammed after some time. Also, they are really heavy which I don't like.
I don't have much of a threat of a bike stealing where I live and just want to keep locks for my mental peace. But after having past experiences and getting the locks jammed, I really want to buy a lock which I can break easily.
Please recommend.
Thanks.

Comment: Be awate that "Questions seeking product/service/learning material recommendations or item valuations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly.". Only generalized recommendations can be made.

Comment: Only cheap locks get jammed. I've got expensive locks decades old that have never given me an ounce of trouble. A lock you can break easily is a lock a thief can break easily, so why bother locking the bike at all, if that's the route you want. If you want security and a lock that doesn't jam, buy a better lock.

Comment: Buy cheap, buy twice (specifically for locks,I would say buy cheap, buy 20 times).
Buy a good quality one, but small, and you are set.

Comment: @PeterDuniho in some places, locks are used more to prevent others from taking the wrong bike, than to prevent deliberate theft (kids riding bikes off the dock, people riding the wrong bike home due to inattention or inebriation etc.). Where I work, bike theft is very rare compared to bike “borrowing”. A few years ago, a thief cut a lock, on a fairly new bike outside its owner’s place of employment. His insurance paid for the bike, and the theft was *front page* news. Otherwise, bikes here tend to show up again after a few days. Some bikes are locked to prevent that, and many are not locked.

Comment: @Pisco: be that as it may, I fail to see the value in treating the lock as disposable. An even less expensive lock than whatever the OP is using now is _more_ likely to get stuck and require breaking. Eventually, one would spend as much on all the cheap locks one is using and breaking, as one would spend on a single good lock that can work reliably for the duration.

Comment: This is one of the most extreme XY problems I've seen

Comment: I've unjammed locks more times than I can count by dripping some chain lube into the keyhole and where the lock connects. Takes about 10 seconds and the lock is good to go indefinitely.

Comment: It may be simply a legal requirement to lock the bicycle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect your question is framed from the point of view of your experiences.  Any weak lock that can be defeated by a tool in your pocket can be defeated by the same tool anyone else carries.

---

Instead of wanting a lock that is weaker, you might consider a lock that is more robust, AND to perform periodic maintenance on the lock like you would with your bike.  A routine oil does wonders to prevent crunchiness.

Consider buying a lock that has some way of shedding water, rather than collecting the water and rusting.

You might choose a lock with brass construction (brass doesn't rust) or perhaps stainless steel.

Another solution is to make sure the lock hangs in such a way that the keyhole is not facing upward.

---

If you really want a weak lock, get a velcro cable tie.  It provides no security other than against a snatch-and-run.  But its reusable, soft on the frame and won't scratch paint.    You can also clip your helmet's chin strap around the forks and through a wheel.   Security offered is basically zero.

[image]

Comment: Use enough zip ties and any bike is secure. May be equally as hard for you to to remove though.